# Convert english word to hindi in tcpdf dynamically php

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have created a bus ticket booking software. I need to convert place value into **Hindi language**. I have used **tcpdf** for printing ticket.

For this I used this code:

```
$pdf->SetFont('kruti', '', 10 ,'true');
$htmls .= '<div style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Jaipur</div>';
```

Please help me.

Comment: And what is the exact problem?

Comment: Its not convert in hindi. Its shows jaipur

Comment: Can you please gave me way to convert english to hindi dynamically

Comment: I have no idea about hindi language nor kruti font, but, how about to configure your css font-family to kruti instead of Verdana, arial, etc. ?? Or, what about to have translations in a table and to pass to tcpdf translate words?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation, we have

```
SetFont(string family[,string style[,string size]])
```

so here

Instead of trying `kruti` use `Kruti Dev 010`
From the web, I have found,

> **Font Name** : Kruti Dev 010
>
> **Font Family Name** : Kruti Dev 010

```
$pdf->SetFont('Kruti Dev 010', '', 10 ,'true');
$htmls .= '<div style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Jaipur</div>';
```